# MySQL price field insert $ and comma

Tags: php, mysql

I have a column called listPrice in a MySQL table that is just the value (example: 5000000).

Currently I am doing a simple select as part of a xml export function.

```
 SELECT listPrice, mls FROM table
```

How do I alter the MySQL query to insert a $ and comma to the value where appropriate so I can have this formatted properly when the xml is generated?

Comment: paste php code please

Comment: You cant insert text into INT, Double etc, You will have to change to VARCHAR or similar. Also means no math calculations.

Comment: Despite what they say, I don't think the OP really wants to INSERT. I think they just want to display. Issues of display are best handled at the application level/presentation layer. That way, your end user can easily customize the display for themselves without troubling your database or even your server!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this

```
select CONCAT('$',format(listPrice, 2)) as formatted, mls from table
```

Answer (score 2):

You can add $ to your results like this

```
SELECT CONCAT( listPrice,  '$' ) AS listPrice, mls FROM table
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [mysql concat](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat) if really needed:
If listPrice is 5000000 this query will have the value **$5000000$,$** for row "var":

```
SELECT CONCAT('$',listPrice,'$,$') AS var FROM table;
```

And also [FORMAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_format) :

```
SELECT CONCAT('$',FORMAT(listPrice,2),'$,$') AS var FROM table;
```

to output **$5,000,000.00$,$**